# passing dictionary to view ,with multiple key:value pairs

Tags: python, django

```
def status_(request,id):
    
    stages=['Vendor Quotation','Estimate Generation','Purchase Requsition','Purchase Order','Provision To Invoice','Reimbursement Invoice','Request Receipt#(PTI+RI+PO)','Receipt# Received(Updated PTI)','Request Sales Tax Invoice','Uploaded to Jazz Portal']    
    ctx={'invoice':Invoices.objects.get(pk=id),'stages':stages}
    return render(request,"Invoices/status.html",ctx)
```

Hi I am trying to pass multiple objects of data for displaying to the template for displaying , I am creating a `ctx` dictionary with multiple 2 key value pairs ,second Key-value pair is array ,when i access this array  in by using

```
{% for idx in range(0,len(ctx.get("stages")) %}
```

I get following parsing error

```
**Could not parse the remainder: '(0,len(ctx.get("stages"))' from 'range(0,len(ctx.get("stages"))'**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make function calls in Django templates with parameters, hence the above wiull not work, but likely you do not need this anyway, you can simply enumerate with:

```
{% for stage in stages %}
    {{ stage }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you really need to enumerate, then you can pass a range object through the context, but then probably a next problem pops up: you can not subscript with a variable either. It will require using a lot of extra template filters, making it very complicated. Templates are normally not used to implement *business logic*, therefore Django has a template engine that does not support complicated function calls, etc. to give the developer an incentive to move the business logic to the view.

Comment: how can i get the length of the stages

Comment: @Janson: `{{ stages|length }}`.

Comment: @Janson You can use `{{ forloop.counter }}` if you just want to helpfully number your rendered html.

Comment: {% if forloop.counter==1 %}  how can i use  forloop.counter inside if to check its value and render some html